# how to call a C# method without linq in "Group by query"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, group-by

I wrote a LINQ query that works fine , that LINQ query have a group by statement that use my C# methods for converting DateTime from Miladi to hejri. **now my purpose is** : writing this linq query in raw sql

this is my **NewsModel** class :

```
public class News
{
    public News()
    {
        Months = new List<string>();
    }        
    public int NewsID { get; set; }
    [Required]        
    public string FaTitle { get; set; }        
    public string FaBody { get; set; }        
    public string EnTitle { get; set; }        
    public string EnBody { get; set; }        
    public bool IsImageActive { get; set; }        
    public string NewsImage { get; set; }        
    public string NewsImage2 { get; set; }        
    public bool IsArchived { get; set; }        
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]        
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DateUpdate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]        
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DateCreate { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int Years { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<String> Months { get; set; }
}
}
```

and in my controller :

```
var Archives = from Records in news
    group Records by new { Years = date.GetYear(Records.DateUpdate, ConvertTime.UTCtoIran) } into GYears
    select new { Years = GYears.Key.Years, Months = (from r in GYears group r by date.GetMonthName(r.DateUpdate) into Gmonths select Gmonths.Key) }.ToExpando();

ViewBag.Archive = Archives;
```

now i want to do that with raw sql query, as u see in LINQ query i used `date.GetYear` and `date.GetMonthName` methods that are C# methods but i can't use them in a raw sql query like `"select date.GetYear(foo) ..."`

Comment: Years is a field that query returned it `select foo as Years`

Comment: A is the result of `db.news.SqlQuery("select Year(foo) as Years from news");` and now how can i have access Years and instead the default function Year , i want to use my own function in c#

Comment: @LukStorms the index of A is integer can't be string

Comment: So you're asking for a way for your SQL statement to call a C# function?  You'll have to build that function into an assembly, reference that assembly from the SQL server, create a UDF that uses that assembly's function, and call that UDF in the GROUP BY.  There's nothing significantly simpler that that.

Comment: @DStanley yes with build-in functions in sql i can get the `2011{1,2,3} , 2010{5,9,12}` result for example but i want to convert them to something like `1395{tir,khordad,ordi}, 1394{far,dey,bah}` , is there anyway to do this easily ?

Comment: There's not an easy way to call C# functions from SQL, no.  Whether you can recreate that logic in a SQL function depends completely on what the function _does_.

Comment: @DStanley ok. now how can i get the query and after it convert them , in other words suppose i have a LINQ query (at the end of my question) that want to write the alternative version in sql query way plz help me.

Comment: @DStanley hi, i edited my question again to be more clear plz see it again ty

Comment: Your question and desire are clear, but the answer is the same - **there's no simple way to call a C# function from SQL**.  You _might_ be able to write a function _equivalent to_ `getyear` in SQL but that depends entirely on what the function does, and you haven't shown that to know for sure.

Comment: @DStanley so in asp classic without mvc and EF and LINQ what can we do ? and i don't know how LINQ does that ? i know LINQ convert our LINQ statement to sql query and send it to database , so how it does it ?

Comment: EF (like other Linq providers) has a Linq interpreter that analyses the query as a set of expressions and function calls, determines if each expression has a SQL equivalent, and builds the SQL statement from there.  I cannot see what `GetYear` does (though I could make a pretty good guess) to know what the SQL equivalent is. If you have a Linq query that works you can get a Linq profiler to get the SQL it generates and try using that.

Comment: ty @DStanley u can do this as an answer to mark it as correct , btw the `GetYear` is in a dll file and it use itself from many other assembely so i think we can't write an alternative version of it in sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments, you want to get the year with the list of corresponding months in the table records, to do this you don't need the local function:

```
string query = "select DISTINCT DATEPART(YEAR, dbo.News.DateUpdate) as Year, "
             + "DATEPART(YEAR, dbo.News.DateUpdate) as Month"
             + "from dbo.News";

List<DataHolder> A = db.News.SqlQuery(query).ToList();

var results = (from a in A
                group a by a.Year into grp
                select new
                {
                    Year = grp.Key,
                    Months = grp.Select(x => x.Month).ToList()
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: i want the second solution ty for answer but the problem is in your second solution there is no A.Years ! VS don't know about Years

Comment: @Saeid You don't have` Years` in `News` class ?

Comment: no i don't have it , it's just the result of sql query "select foo as Years"

Comment: @Saeid you need to add it `public int Years { set; get; }` to class 'Years' or the value will be lost !

Comment: there is no class Years i have this `List<News> A = db.News.SqlQuery(query).ToList();` a A list that i expect it has A.Year field but i just have the fields in the news table yet !

Comment: in the sql query ` "select YEAR(dbo.News.DateUpdate) as Years, MONTH(dbo.News.DateUpdate) as Months from dbo.News group by dbo.News.DateUpdate"` my purpose is to change YEAR function with a c# function because i can't create my own function in sql so i have to write it in c#

Comment: @Saeid you must have `Years` field in `News` class, or the value will no be mapped.

Comment: i try to do that and after it i will report u here ty

Comment: @Saeid Now i got your point, you need to convert `DateUpdate` to `Year` using c# , please copy and paste `News` class to your question, so that i can show you how to exactly do what you want.

Comment: i did it. i paste my model class here

Comment: @Saeid do you wan to extract the month part from the date column `DateUpdate` ? You can do that in c#, i updated my answer you can check it. But if you just want that, you can also do that in SQL which is better `select DATEPART(MONTH, dbo.News.DateUpdate) as Years`

Comment: @Saeid can you show the implementation for `myfunc()` also ?

Comment: thank you , i need to extract years and each months in years (for an archive) and then convert their localization to Persian calendar

Comment: thank you again this code is good but not for my special aim my purpose is to get an array of Years that each year have an array of Months
ex : 
2011{1,2,3} , 2010{5,9,12} , 2009{2,3,5}
and after i get this from db i want to convert them to our calander :
1395{tir,khordad,ordi}, 1394{far,dey,bah}, 1393{es,mor,tir}

Comment: @Saeid your Sql query groups by Date and not by year.

Comment: @Saeid so you don't want any other information ? Just a year and a list of months for that year from db.

Comment: yes just a year and  a list of months for that year and apply my converting function to them ofc

Comment: @Saeid you don't need `myfunc()` to do this. I updated the entire answer with the solution. Sorry, but your original question was not clear.

Comment: the variable `results ` is a LINQ query that i used something like it and works fine but i now i want to work with raw sql query and instead of using DATEPART function which is a build-in function of sql, i want to use my own c# function

Comment: @Saeid i don't understand what your c# function exactly does. Can you post it in your question ?

Comment: i edited my question and did it , the function is in a dll file but i posted the LINQ version i used. i want exactly a raw sql version with same result as LINQ query version

Comment: hi , i edited my question to be more clear plz see it again ty